# Debugging JS in IE-7

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, javascript-debugger

I use Firebug for debugging JS and HTML in Mozilla a LOT but every now and then I run into an IE-only JavaScript bug, which are really hard to locate (ex: error on line 802 Char 1, when the source HTML only has 300 lines).

I badly need to have a lightweight JS tool (like firebug) for IE, something I can install in seconds on a client's PC if I run into an error and then uninstall. Some Microsoft tools take some serious download and configuration time.

Any suggestions please? I am using IE-7

Comment: have you tried [firebug lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where have you been buddy ?? :)
From IE-8 onwards, there is an in-built tool called IE Developer Toolbar packaged with IE. But you can still download and intall it anytime you want for IE-6 and 7. Its only 600kb or something.

Also, there is Firebug Lite , for any browser other than firefox. If you are too much used to Firebug, this will be good for you.

Hope this helps !!

Comment: yeah.. FB lite will be great and lightweight too !!.. but has bit limited features than original FB for FF

Answer (score 1):

[DebugBar](http://www.debugbar.com/) good, and is free for personal use. You have to pay for it if using commercially though.

You can use IE-8 or above and still use the browser mode to check IE7 compatibility during development and it comes with a very good [developer toolbar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg589507%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: @Atirek ... I missed this. IE-8 gives backward compatibility to IE-7. One shot solution to all problems ... Thanks Arun !!

Comment: @ArunPJohny Are you the Arun P Johny that used to work at Nisai in Stockton?